# How to use modsecurity with lighttpd

Tags: centos, lighttpd, mod-security

I'm not an expert and I'm looking to use modsecurity with lighttpd

Can someone explain me how to compile or install modsecurity for lighttpd because I can't find any documentation online

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it appears that as of july 2018 there is no "connector" from libmodsec to lightty. Only apache and nginx. It doesn't look like a lot of work to write such a connector, but nothing presently exists.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote lighttpd connector to libmodsecurity here: https://github.com/gstrauss/lighttpd1.4/tree/mod_security3
The connector has not been tested and it is not currently recommended since I was not very impressed with the design or performance of libmodsecurity once I peeked into their library code.  You're welcome to try it out and give feedback on github or in the [lighttpd forums](https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/boards/2)